# How to add smiles for java chat application

Tags: java, swing, sockets, emoji

I want to add emoji for a java swing chat application.But I couldn't success yet. Anyone helps me.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no universal standard for a "smile" icon.

Chat clients that support smilies and other icons send a special code across the wire that the chat client interprets and renders as a smile.

You can take the same approach.

A simpler but more limited approach is to use the Unicode Emoticons (make sure they are properly rendered in your client app though, as not every platform properly renders every Unicode character.)

http://unicodeemoticons.com/

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

Firts, you need print on screen the messages using a JEditorPane, this Swing Component allows you print images and text.

[Display images using JEditorPane](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077472/core-java/java-tip-109--display-images-using-jeditorpane.html)

The next step is create a "scanner method" to identify "Unicode Emoticons" like ':)' or ':P', etc. If the scanner identify a "unicode emoticon" change this characters for a string with the image corresponding.